# Detecting invalid WKT in text column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text, invalid-data

I've got a whole load of WKT data in a SQL Server table, of which I'm trying to detect the validity.

I'm currently doing a query like this:

```
UPDATE f SET 
    f."CurrentGeomValid" = geometry::STGeomFromText(f."GEOM_CURRENT",29900).STIsValid()
FROM "Feature" f 
WHERE f."CurrentGeomValid" IS NULL;
```

(Basically updating a column with the geometry validity).  I'm hitting an issue when the WKT is completely invalid, for example:

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 10 10, 0 0) (100 100, 200 100, 200 200, 100 200, 100 100))
```

The initial loop of this polygon doesn't have enough points and gets me a message like so:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24305: The Polygon input is not valid because the ring does not have enough distinct points. Each ring of a polygon must contain at least three distinct points.
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.Execute(Transition transition)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.EndFigure()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseLineStringText()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParsePolygonText()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseMultiPolygonText()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
```

The issue seems to be that the STGeomFromText function is failing to read the invalid geometry so that the STIsValid function can tell me that it's invalid!

I can certainly write some .NET code with an exception handler and process my dataset row by row.

Is there a way of doing this in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a stored procedure that will do it, no CLR needed, unfortunately it can't be a function because it uses TRY... CATCH...

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestWKT]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestWKT]

GO
------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE TestWKT(
    @wkt varchar(max),
    @srid int) 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @valid bit;

BEGIN TRY
    SET @valid = geometry::STGeomFromText(@wkt, @srid).STIsValid();
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @valid = 0
END CATCH

SELECT @valid;

END
------------------------------------------------
GO

exec TestWKT 'garbage', 4326

exec TestWKT 'POINT(-84 32)', 4326
```